# Relative links in tvml?

Tags: swift, tvos, tvml

Is it possible to use relative links in tvml? I've never had a problem using them in a webpage but just can't get it to work in my tvml docs.

From my swift:

```
static let TVBaseURL = "http://localhost:9001/"
```

This currently works from my tvml which is located at `http://localhost:9001/templates/home.xml`

```
 <lockup onselect="getDocument('templates/Featured.xml')">
   <img src="http://localhost:9001/graphics/icons/ICON_featured.png" width="313" height="600" />
 </lockup>
```

Note that the `onselect` link is relative and works fine. However this doesn't work...

```
<lockup onselect="getDocument('templates/Featured.xml')">
  <img src="../graphics/icons/ICON_featured.png" width="313" height="600" />
</lockup>
```

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on how you define YOUR `getDocument` function. But from your code, most likely it looks a bit like this one from the [official TVML Programming Guide, sec 8-3](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TVMLKitJS/Conceptual/TVMLProgrammingGuide/PlayingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016718-CH13-SW1).

```
function getDocument(extension) {
    var templateXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = baseURL + extension;

    loadingTemplate();
    templateXHR.responseType = "document";
    templateXHR.addEventListener("load", function() {pushPage(templateXHR.responseXML);}, false);
    templateXHR.open("GET", url, true);
    templateXHR.send();
}
```

Which uses a pre-set baseURL like your code does. Thus, your get document support relative links. (and not universal link. putting the full http://localhost:9001/index.xml will break it.)

in this example, the `XMLHttpRequest` object `open` function, takes the full url, not the relative one. Read more about [XMLHttpRequest open here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open).

In short. Nothing is relative here.

However, you can do something similar with the power of Javascript.

When you get a hold of the XML document, you can find all the tag with `document.getElementsByTagName("img")`, which give you a list of the image element. Then all it is left to do it to look at each of them with `.item(i)`, get their source attribute by `.getAttribute('src')`, see if it start with http or https, and if not, set the new one by `.setAttribute('src', baseUrl+imagePath)`

Comment: You're right that my code is straight from the official TVML Programming Guide, sec 8-3. I think I understand your solution, but is there a way to modify the getDocument function so that all links, regardless of the type of element, can be relative?

Comment: not that I know of. Apple doesn't get the image resources via the getDocument function.